# On an XSD element, can I set maxOccurs depending on a grandparent node's attribute value?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I want to define the two xml structures below using a single XSD.

```
<grandparent action="SUBMIT">
   <parent>
       <child value="blah"/>
   </parent>
<grandparent>

<grandparent action="CANCEL">
   <parent>
   </parent>
<grandparent>
```

Rules I want to enforce:

- If action equals "SUBMIT", maxOccurs for `<child>` should be unbounded
- If action equals "CANCEL", maxOccurs for `<child>` should be 0 (i.e. it should not appear)

Is it possible to enforce these kind of rules with XSD?

Comment: No, it's not.............................

Comment: @Deniel - as Ed has explained clearly above, you can't do this kind of conditional stuff with XSD.

Comment: @Hugh - I struggled to think of a useful elaboration, but couldn't think of any.  I could get into what you _can_ do, but it wouldn't help the OP with the problem at hand.  It felt like he knows how to use XSD - just was hoping against hope that he'd missed some feature that would help with this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this kind of stuff in XSD 1.0 - but you can in XSD 1.1 (implemented currently in recent releases of Saxon and Xerces). There are two possible approaches:

(a) Conditional type assignment: have two different types for grandparent, and select which one to validate against base on the attribute value

(b) assertions: leave maxOccurs unbounded in the grammar, and add an assertion to grandparent along the lines `test="if (@ACTION='cancel') then empty(*/child) else true()"`